# Date generate from start to end date in java

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a list of dates from a given start and end date. I found the solution in stack overflow . But, the code gives the distribution starting from the month of January. I am unable to find why. Please help me out.

starting , ending are String with **format 'yyyy-mm-dd'**.
 duration is the **Arraylist** I am using to store the dates.

```
List<Date> duration = new ArrayList<Date>();
         List<Date> date_req = new ArrayList<Date>();
            Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();


        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        Date date_st = formatter.parse(starting);
        Date date_en = formatter.parse(ending);

            int init=0;
            start.setTime(date_st);
            Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
            end.setTime(date_en);
            end.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); //Add 1 day to endDate to make sure endDate is included into the final list
            while (start.before(end)) {
                duration.add(init,start.getTime());
                start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
                init=init+1;
            }
          System.out.println(duration);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What output you are getting from this ?

Comment: If you want to add `start.getTime()` at the end of the list, it is clearer to do just `duration.add(start.getTime())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format should be 
    `DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Using mm for Month is the reason you get your year starting from JAN

Comment: i won't mind that dear.but when i clicked that tick mark ,it said "you can click it in 2 minutes",then it said one minute.:-)

Answer (score 0):

`mm` stands for minutes, for months you have to use `MM`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with minor changes as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException,
            FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
        List<Date> duration = new ArrayList<Date>();


        String starting = "2014-04-01";
        String ending = "2014-04-30";

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        Date date_st = formatter.parse(starting);
        Date date_en = formatter.parse(ending);

        int init = 0;
        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        start.setTime(date_st);
        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
        end.setTime(date_en);
        end.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); // Add 1 day to endDate to make sure
                                            // endDate is included into the
                                            // final list
        while (start.before(end)) {
            duration.add(start.getTime());
            start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }

        for (Date date : duration) {
            System.out.println(date);
        }

    }
```